# python plotly show more values on x axis

Tags: python, plotly

I used plotly in python to show a line chart about the revenue vs date.

The y axis only have 17 values, but x axis have 31 values from 0701 to 0731. For now, the x axis only show 17 values but I want all date from 0701 to 0731 show on the x axis even 0719-0731 are empty.  So is there a way to show it? Thanks

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = table['date'].str[5:].values.tolist()     #['0701','0702',...,'0731']
y = (table['revenue']/10000)[:-1].apply(lambda x: format(x, '.1f')).values.tolist()     

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y,text=y,mode="lines+markers+text",
            line=dict(color='firebrick', width=4)))
fig.update_layout(
    width=900,height=650,
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)')



fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=True,linecolor='black',ticks='outside',range=[-1,32])
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=True, showticklabels=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='lightgrey',linecolor='black',ticks='outside')
```